# Where to define enums

Tags: c++

Say I want to create a card class. and want to have enums for the cards

2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,J,Q,K,A

Where's the best place to define this, the header file Card.h or Card.cpp?

Comment: Of course, numbers are not valid identifier names...

Comment: It really depends on what parts of your code need access to the enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this, in the definition of your card class:

```
class Card
{
public:
   typedef enum
   {
      Two = 0,
      Three,
      Four,
      Five,
      Six,
      Seven,
      Eight,
      Nine,
      Ten,
      Jack,
      Queen,
      King,
      Ace
   } Face;
};
```

Or C++11:

```
class Card
{
public:
   enum Face: unsigned char
   { 
      Two = 0,
      Three,
      Four,
      Five,
      Six,
      Seven,
      Eight,
      Nine,
      Ten,
      Jack,
      Queen,
      King,
      Ace
   };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

It's going to be a new **type**. So I would probably put it on the header file in case I need it in other compilation units.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
class CCard
{
public:
    CCard( void );
    virtual ~CCard( void );

    // Card face type
    enum eCardFaceType
    {
       Face_2,
       Face_3,
       Face_4,
       Face_5,
       Face_6,
       Face_7,
       Face_8,
       Face_9,
       Face_10,
       Face_Jack,
       Face_Queen,
       Face_King
     };

     // Card suit
     enum eSuitType
     {
         Suit_Clubs,
         Suit_Diamonds,
         Suit_Hearts,
         Suit_Spades
     };

    // Internal data.
protected:
     eCardFaceType m_face;
     eSuitType  m_Suit;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to define the enum is to declare it in header file. So, that you can use it anywhere you want by including that header file during compilation.